# Does the Path of the Beast barbarian's Bestial Soul ability affect high jumps?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, barbarian

We had a discussion at our table regarding the Bestial Soul feature of the [Path of the Beast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheBeast) barbarian. The feature says

> When you jump, you can make a Strength (Athletics) check and extend your jump by a number of feet equal to the check’s total. You can make this special check only once per turn.

In the [PHB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/adventuring#Jumping) it says

> **High Jump**. When you make a high jump, you leap into the air a number of feet equal to 3 + your Strength modifier if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing high jump, you can jump only half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement. In some circumstances, your DM might allow you to make a Strength (Athletics) check to jump higher than you normally can.

It feels like the ability is only intended to apply to the long jump, but it does not say that specifically. When reading online discussions about the ability they are all about the long jump, not the high jump.

So why does or doesn't it affect the high jump?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The feature applies to every type of jump.

The Bestial Soul feature allows to add the result of the STR check to a jump, it does not make any distinction between long, high, or standing jump: therefore, this bonus can be added to any kind of jumping movement.

For comparison, have a look at the Totem Spirit feature of the [Path of the Totem Warrior](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheTotemWarrior):

> **Tiger**
>
> While raging, you can add 10 feet to your long jump distance and 3 feet to your high jump distance. The spirit of the tiger empowers your leaps.

This feature explicitly states that different jumps get different bonus.

Another game feature that specifies to which kind of jump you may apply a bonus is the  Second-Story Work from Thief subclass:

> **Second-Story Work**
>
> [...]
>
> In addition, when you make a running jump, the distance you cover increases by a number of feet equal to your Dexterity modifier.

This is very similar to the the Remarkable Athlete from the [Champion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#Champion) subclass for fighters, the latter using Strength mod instead of Dexterity one.

Answer (score -1):

### There are no secret rules

The feature applies to jumps.